# General method for computing matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $A' = Q^{-1} A P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $A'$ be arbitrary equivalent matrices of order $m \times n$. We know there must exist two regular matrices $P$ and $Q$ which satisfy $A' = Q^{-1} A P$.

My first approach to calculating those is as follows:

1. Calculate regular matrices S and T such that $S A T = H$, where H is the matrix obtained by row and column reducing matrix A
2. Do the same for A': $S' A' T' = H$, where H is the same as before (because A and A' are equivalent)
3. Equate and obtain than $A'= (S')^{-1} S A T (T')^{-1}$

Therefore, $((S')^{-1} S)^{-1}$ is $Q$ and $T (T')^{-1}$ gives P without any extra overhead.

As you can observe, this is a very tedious method for obtaining $Q$ and $P$ by hand, so are there any shortcuts or tricks to be used in general or in some specific case?

Comment: By "regular matrix" do you mean invertible matrix?

Comment: I would have done the same but with SVDs